# How to Edit a Row in JuliaDB?

Tags: julia, juliadb

Is there a way to edit a field in JuliaDB? I want to modify column `y` where column `x == 4`.

```
using JuliaDB
t = table((x = [1,4,5,6], y = [2,2,24,5]))
```

I found a thing somewhere showing how to do this.. but it didn't work any more.. it used `merge` or `push` I believe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a lot of digging and just mashing of keys... I figured it out.

```
using JuliaDB
t = table((x = [1,4,5,6], y = [2,2,24,5]))
Table with 4 rows, 2 columns:
x  y
─────
1  2
4  2
5  24
6  5

t = transform(t, :y => (:x, :y) => row -> row.x == 4 ? 99.0 : row.y)

Table with 4 rows, 2 columns:
x  y
───────
1  2
4  99.0
5  24
6  5
```